# Angular 2 Better Message Service

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I have a MessageService class that have a setMessage method which triggers an event and also a MainComponent class which is parent component of all components that listens to this event. so the event will be fire and MainComponent will catch it and everything is ok. but there is one problem. that I want when user changes the component e.g.: navigates from dashboard component to users component the message automatically been destroyed. but here this is not happens and the message will still showing to user. I wrote a timer to delete the message after a time but I want to know if there is a better way to implement this or not

this is my message service class :

```
import {ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

export class MessageService{

public messageSource;
public messageEvent;


constructor(){
    this.messageSource  = new ReplaySubject(1);
    this.messageEvent   = this.messageSource.asObservable();
}


public setMessage(message){
    this.messageSource.next(message);
    window.setTimeout(()=>{
        this.destruct();
    },5000);
}

public destruct(){
    this.messageSource.next(null);
}
```

and this is my main component class:

```
export class MainComponent extends BaseComponent{


constructor(public router:Router,public authService:AuthService,public messageService:MessageService){
    super(router);
    this.messageService.messageEvent.subscribe(msg => {
        this.message = msg;
    });

}



public logout(){
    this.authService.removeToken();
    this.permission.user = null;
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
}

}
```

Comment: you shoudl switch your javascript tag for typescript

Comment: can you give more detail ?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the removal of the message within the component's ngOnDestroy life-cycle hook. It will fire when the component is destroyed.

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // your code will go here
  }
}
```

Read more here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnDestroy-class.html

Comment: I tried this but the main component as I said is the parent component so the ngDestroy wont call on it. So in this way I have to call this function in all components that I think the way implemented now is far better than this.